# Input range thumb not changing in Chrome despite using `-webkit-appearance: none`

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I am struggling to change the styles for the input range thumb in Chrome despite using -webkit-appearance: none.

See the full code in the codepen here https://codepen.io/maz-sm-22/pen/GRXyzNv.

`html`

```
<body>
   <input type='range' value='50'/>
</body>
```

`CSS`

```
body {
  height: 100vh; 
  background-color: #36024F; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 60%;
  height: 16px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(203, 124, 243), rgb(203, 124, 243));
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb, 
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fefcff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track,
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track  {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

`JS`

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(value); 
    e.target.style.backgroundSize = `${value}% 100%`
}
    
document.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange)
```

It is working as expected in Firefox.

If anyone has any idea as to what's going on, I would greatly appreciate your insight.

Thanks!

Comment: No browser has needed the `-webkit` prefix in many, many years. Remove that.

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue styling `-webkit-slider-thumb` / `-moz-range-thumb` pseudo element. It appears to me that chrome fails to match the element as long as `-moz-range-thumb` appears in selector. The only workaround I can think of is duplicating styles

```css
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fefcff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fefcff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

I am not sure this is a chrome bug or a feature, but reported crbug here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1486850